# matplotlib log graph not showing the range defined

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib to plot log graph of 10

```
plt.ylim(10^-10, 10^2)
```

as shown above, I want to plot the range of 10^-10 to 10^2
however I only get 10^-4 to 10^0, the upper and lower part are cut out
how to fix it to show all the log range?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to calculate 10 to the power of -10 and 2? If yes please see [python operators](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_operators.asp).

By using `^` you are XORing the two values. You should use `**` for power operation.